# How can I find a project that has uncommited changes to source control?

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins, subversive

I am writing a plug-in and I have to find if some project existing in the workspace has uncommitted files to SVN. I am using subversive to interact with the SVN repository. I am sure there i a way, subversive does it :), but I could not find the place where it does. To have as an example.

Do you know how to achieve this ? Or where to look for an example ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never meddled with this code myself... but the decorators subversive puts on files in your package explorer (the little '>' for uncommited changes) are provided through the org.eclipse.ui.decorators extension point. So for an example, you'd need to import the org.eclipse.team.svn.ui plugin in your workspace (File > import > plugins and fragments) and look at its plugin.xml to find the decorator that does this work (if I am not mistaken, it is org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.decorator.SVNLightweightDecorator).

Good luck on this, team APIs are not the easiest to use ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand, but `svn status` tells you which files are under version control, and which aren't.